# Android: what kind of UI component is it and how can I create it?

Tags: android, user-interface, menu

I want to create menu like on screenshots below. What kind of UI component is it and how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Navigation Drawer. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) is the link to official documentation of this feature. [This](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) link will be helpful as it provides complete example.